# 32 bit intel stack frame format string exploit

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

I have a program that looks like this

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char *input)
{
    char buffer[64];
    strncpy(buffer, input, sizeof(buffer));
    printf(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(argv[1]);
}
```

I compile my program with all stack related protection turned off.

> gcc fmthck.c -w -m32 -O0 -ggdb -std=c99 -static -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -fno-pie   -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -fno-stack-protector -z norelro -z execstack -o hacks
>
> sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0

Then I supply the compiled program with the following arguments:

> ./hacks "AAAA %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p"

And I get an output that looks like this

> AAAA 0xffffd3cb 0x40 0x8048d3c 0x41414141 0x2e702520 0x252e7025 0x70252e70 0x2e70252e 0x252e7025 0x70252e70

I know that A=0x41 in HEX. So I'm *guessing* that the starting address of the buffer corresponds to the 4th %p. **I was just wondering what the stuff around it means**. I was given a stack diagram that looks like this. I know that 0x8048d3c corresponds to the return address but some things don't line up

High Memory Address

- Input parameters
- Return Address
- Saved Frame Pointer
- Local Variables
- Saved Registers

Low Memory address

Could someone please elaborate on what is happening to the stack as I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile your program with option -S, the compiler will generate assembly output which you can examine. In your case, the relevant generated code is:

```
foo:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
     subl    $88, %esp
    movl    $64, 8(%esp)
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    leal    -72(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    strncpy
    leal    -72(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
```

Your output was

```
    AAAA 0xffffd3cb 0x40 0x8048d3c 0x41414141 0x2e702520 0x252e7025 0x70252e70 0x2e70252e 0x252e7025 0x70252e70
```

which has to be interpreted as a piece of system stack at the moment of invocation of `printf`. The meaning of the output is:

```
AAAA       == string from argument printed by printf
0xffffd3cb == garbage left from previous function invocation, in fact the input argument argv[1] previously sent to `strncpy`
0x40       == garbage left from previous function invocation, in fact it is the constant 64 previously sent to strncpy
0x8048d3c  == ??? I don't know why gcc left this unused space.
0x41414141 0x2e70252 ... is the content of local variable `buffer` which contains the string "AAAA %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p".
```

Return address from your function as well as saved base pointer are beyond your output.